# Best way to do input with racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

What's the best way to read input from stdin in racket?

In particular I'd like something like `cin` from c++ or `scanf` from c where I specify the types of things I want read and they are returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do pretty much everything you want to... at the low level, I would suggest (read-line) and (read-bytes).  For higher-level processing (as e.g. scanf does), I would suggest a regexp-match on the input.  For instance

```
(regexp-match #px" *([0-9]+)" (current-input-port))
```

Answer (score 10):

[`read-line`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html?q=read-line#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-line%29%29) is easy. To be portable across Unix and Windows, additional option is required.

```
(read-line (current-input-port) 'any)
```

> Return and linefeed characters are detected after the conversions that
>   are automatically performed when reading a file in text mode. For
>   example, reading a file in text mode on Windows automatically changes
>   return-linefeed combinations to a linefeed. Thus, when a file is
>   opened in text mode, 'linefeed is usually the appropriate read-line
>   mode.

So, 'any is required to be portable when the input port is not a file (standard input).

Test program:

```
#lang racket
(let loop ()
    (display "Input: ")
    (define a (read-line (current-input-port) 'any))
    (printf "input: ~a, length: ~a, last character: ~a\n"
        a
        (string-length a)
        (char->integer (string-ref a (- (string-length a) 1))))
    (loop))
```

In Windows, replace `(read-line (current-input-port) 'any)` with `(read-line)` and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, `read-line` should be portable across Unix and Windows without setting different options (mentioned further down in the docs).

Comment: This results in: `; string-ref: contract violation
;   expected: exact-nonnegative-integer?
;   given: -1
;   argument position: 2nd
;   other arguments...:
;    ""
; Context:
;  stdin:1:1 loop` (Racket 6.10.1)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `read` procedure for the general case. If the data type to be read is known beforehand, use `read-char`, `read-string`, `read-bytes`.

Also, take a look at [this](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/83527750/) implemenation for reading formatted input - a `scanf` in Scheme.

Comment: Read seems to have problems if there are parentheses in the input

Comment: What kind of problems? it works fine for me, a parenthesized expression is returned as a list of symbols - as expected. And did you look at the library I linked? it's like `scanf` but in Scheme

Comment: For example, try using this as your input: `( 1 2 3`. Then call `(read) (read) (read) (read)`. Instead of yielding four strings (`(`, `1`, `2`, `3`), it yields an error. The library looks great - thanks! I was hoping to find something built-in so I can see what the standard practice is for this sort of thing. John Clements' answer was what I was looking for. I understand what `read` does - it's just not what I was looking for.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez bad link :c

Comment: @cat I updated it with a similar link, the original is gone for good :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basis for line-by-line processing in Racket Scheme. It doesn't split an input line into multiple words, or do typed input, but this seems like a good place to put it.

```
(define (get)
  (read-line (current-input-port)))

(define (put . vs)
  (for-each display vs)
  (displayln ""))

(define (sed fn)
  (let ((line (get)))
    (if (not (eof-object? line))
      (begin
        (fn line)
        (sed fn))
      'true)))

(sed (lambda (line)
  (put "Hello, " line)))
```

Here's one that does split input, also encodes CSV for good measure.

```
(define (get)
  (read-line (current-input-port)))

(define split string-split)
(define sep ",")
(define enc identity)

(define (enc-csv s)
  (string-append "\"" (string-replace s "\"" "\"\"") "\""))
(define enc enc-csv)

(define (put . vs)
  (displayln (string-join (map enc vs) sep)))

(define (sed fn)
  (let ((line (get)))
    (if (not (eof-object? line))
      (begin
        (fn line)
        (sed fn))
      'true)))

(sed (lambda (line)
  (apply put (split line))))
```

This works in Racket. I'm not sure how much of it is specific to Racket. It doesn't seem to work in Chicken or Guile.